# How to find My algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

i need to find a Algorithm that name is Rumor Spreading,it is like travelling salesman problem
but have some difference ,we have 2 salesman,if we have a graph,on some of node we have a salesman too,that take ours and go through the graph,this called Rumor Spreading,the development of Travelling salesman problem,where can i find that Algorithm,or if the name of algorithm is anything else say to me the name of the algorithm,i think the name is Rumor Spreading
Please Help me

Comment: Please, search it on google. Is it something like [this](http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~ggiakkou/papers/conductance_full.pdf) ?

Comment: i did it,but i dont have anything special

Comment: What do you mean with _I dont have anything special_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Google results and this [source you will find complete paper here](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/260-FMIE/Papers/chierichetti_2009.pdf)

Rumour spreading, also known as randomized broadcastor randomized gossip  refers to the following distributed algorithm.

Starting with one source node with a message, the protocol proceeds in a sequence of synchronous rounds with the goal of broadcasting the message, i.e. to deliver it to every node in the network.